# Verbs with までに can they work?

Tags: grammar, usage

I know までに means "by" or "by the time..." And it's used with Time. But I can't help but wonder if I can use it with verbs for example...would this make sense...

> 行ったまでに...
> By the time he came...

Answer (score 2):

までに can only be used with nouns or adverbs of time (1時、あした）or with verbs in non-past form. Even if the action takes place in the past, you must use non-past form before までに. This is common in japanese, because the final verb in the sentence is indicative of the overall temporal, formal qualities.

For example:

> 飛行機がパリに**着くまでに**本を三冊**読んでしまいました**。
>   By the time the aeroplane landed in Paris, I had already  finished reading three books.