# 「ことにまで」についての質問です

Tags: grammar

> 「武士は特別にえらいのだ。百姓や町人が、その武士と同じように名字をつけることはけしからん。」**士· 農· 工· 商という身分のきまりはこんな小さなことにまではっきりとあらわれていたのです。**
>
> 士· 農· 工· 商という身分のきまりはこんな小さな**ことにまで**はっきりとあらわれていたのです

---

あの「ことにまで」はどうやって理解するんですか。

「こんな小さなこと」が「名字」を指していると思っています。

Stackexchangeには「までに」に関する文法に関する質問がありますけど、

[Verbs with までに can they work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41392/verbs-with-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB-can-they-work)

[How does までに work with 少しずつ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48726/how-does-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB-work-with-%E5%B0%91%E3%81%97%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A4)

[What's the difference between まで and までに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7-and-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB)

以上の3つの質問は時間や動詞の時制に関するので、この質問に関係がないはずです

[what does までに mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53963/what-does-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB-mean-in-this-sentence)

この質問のこたえによると、ここにある「にまで」は参考などの意味を認めているので、この質問にの関係があるはずです。

---

質問は、

あの「にまで」は［による］などの意味を含んでいますか。

なお、この句を

> 士· 農· 工· 商という身分は名字がつけられるかどうかによってきめる

として理解してもいいですか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

含んでいないし、理解してもいけません。

「に」は「あらわれる」の場所を表しています。「こんな小さなこと」は「百姓や町人が武士と同じように名字をつけてはいけないこと*」 を指していて、身分の決まりという一般原則を、百姓や町人が名字をつけられないことという具体例の中に見ることができるということです。

「まで」は「も」と同じです。

なお、「百姓や町人が武士と同じように名字をつけられない」というのは、単に公文書に名前を書くときは名字の代わりに自分の村や務めている店の名前を書くということであって、名字がないということではありません。また、百姓や町人であっても武士の養子になれば制約を突破できます。

Comment: 日本の歴史によると、士· 農· 工· 商は武士などの貴族を含んでいますか。

Comment: なお、「こんな小さなこと」は「百姓や町人が武士と同じように名字をつけては **いいとかいけないとか** 」という意味ですか。

Comment: 「士」とは武士階級、つまり墾田永年私財法(743)により新しく得た私有地を相続した人たちの子孫のことです。こんな小さなことについては、私は元の文を読めないのでわかりません。ただ、文の書きぶりからすると程度の低いプロパガンダのようですから、そもそも信用すべきじゃない気がします。

Comment: ちなみに、将棋の戦法のうち「石田」は人名、「美濃」は地名、「矢倉」は店の名前です。発案者がどんな人か想像できますね。

Comment: 「士· 農· 工· 商という身分のきまりはこんな小さなことにまではっきりとあらわれていたのです」の「こんな小さなこと」には「かとか」という意味を含んでいますか。

Comment: 例えば、自分の家族で名字がつけられたら、自分が貴族を認めています。自分の家族で名字がつけなかったら、自分が平民を認めています。

Comment: つまり、自分の身分は名字をつけるかとか決まりますなどの意味。

Comment: @QING いいえ、すべて「いいえ」です。もし、元の文がそう言っているのなら、その元の文がまちがっています。

Comment: "かどうか"です。"かとか"ではありません。すみません

Comment: @QING すいません、質問の意味がわかりません。

Comment: 質問ではありません。元の質問と コメントには文法の間違いがありますので、コメントを残すことで、人々を注意させます。

Comment: @QING では、「例えば…自分が貴族を認めています…平民を認めています」とます形を使ってることが間違いです。

Comment: 正しい言い方は？ありがとうございます。

Comment: @QING 「自分が貴族だと認める…平民だと認める（ということです）」といった具合に…。要は、"to do" is not します but する. ます form is a modal expression that tells the information is listener-oriented. In your example, that part itself is just a hypothetical example.